# PHP Laravel. реализовать присваивание категорий

Tags: php, laravel

Необходимо создать блог, в котором каждой статье будет присваиваться категория. (много к одному)
В БД есть следующие таблицы: articles, categories.

В articles поля:

> title = а; text = b; category_id = 3.

В categories поля:

> id = 3; name = c.

Я хочу, чтобы по значению поля category_id выводилась категория и её данные.
Как такое реализовать?

P.S. надеюсь объяснил нормально

P.P.S. не бейте, pls.

Comment: На каком вы уже этапе: создали миграции, описали модели, задали маршруты, внедрили валидацию ... Или изучили какие-то мануалы, инструкции и что-то не понятно?

Answer (score 0):

Это стандартная задача.
В модели для таблицы articles

```
public function category()
{
   return $this->belongsTo('App\Category');  // App\Category - модель для таблицы categories 
}
```

и можно пользоваться

```
$article->category
```

Почитайте про "Один ко многим (Обратное отношение)", там есть тонкости.

Comment: Хмм. Вылазит ошибка Using $this when not in object context.

P.S. у меня есть модель категорий в которой прописана связь

Comment: Не актуально, ошибку нашёл.

Comment: Похоже вы не в модели прописали, раз $this не определено. А связь в модели категорий вам не поможет - она лишь вернет те статьи, у которых есть данная категория, а вам надо наоборот, так что связь надо прописать в модели статьей.